# How to store text mixed with HTML tags and properly display the tags in a Django and jinja2 project?

Tags: html, django, django-templates

I take text of an article from PostgreSQL database where it is stored in TEXT type and then insert into html template using jinja as in the expample below:

```
<p>{{article.text}}</p>
```

The problem is that atricle should be divided into paragrafs, which means html tags need to be put inside text. I have tried writing html tags inside the text, like is example below:

```
 ...development.</br> Simplicity...
```

However, tags is displayed as a part of an ordinary text.

Are there any options to store text mixed with HTML tags? Or, perhaps, there is an alternitive solution?

Answer (score 0):

You mark the text as "safe" to prevent escaping it with the [**`|safe`** template filter <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/templates/builtins/#safe):

```
<p>
  {{ article.text|safe }}
</p>
```

If you don't mark text as a `SafeString`, it will translate `<` for example to `&lt;`. This is often *wanted* behavior: if you write `1 < 2`, you want to render this as *less than*. If the content is however HTML and you want to skip this escaping mechanism, you mark the text as safe.